# Get selected value of DropDownList in ViewModel (MVC4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view model which have the following two properties:

```
    public List<ContributorModel> Contributors { get; set; }
    public Guid ContributorSelected { get; set; }
```

When setting up the view, the Contributors contains a list of objects, I want to show in a DropDownList. When posting back to the server, I want ContributorSelected to be the value of the DropDownList.

So Inside my form, I've tried:

```
             <div class="formrow">
                 @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Contributors.First().Id,new SelectList(Model.Contributors,"Id","LastName"))
             </div>
```

But I really have no idea how to format my code so ContributorSelected gets the value. Also, when posting back, the model.Contributors is null.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your model is not accepting the selected contributor, your markup should be:

```
<div class="formrow">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.ContributorSelected, new SelectList(Model.Contributors,"Id","LastName"))
</div>
```

Just make sure the `Id` is a Guid so it matches `Model.ContributorSelected`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Very obvious when you've shown it! Will accept answer in 10 min